# Testing Java regex appendReplacement()

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have developed a UI that allows users to define a regex pattern and then a replacement string that is used by `appendReplacement()`.

e.g.

- Pattern - 7(.*)
- Replace pattern - $1

So 71234 would yield 1234.

Is there anyway I can verify that the input pattern and replace pattern are compatible without the user having to enter a matching string?  For example if the replace pattern was `$1$2` then this would throw an exception at runtime.  Can I check for this in advance?

EDIT:

Final solution was to do as aioobe suggested and get the group count by creating a dummy Matcher (not sure why this method isn't on Pattern TBH) and then manually parsing the replace string manually to find which $ group references are present.  Bit fiddly but works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do something like:

```
yourPattern.matcher("").groupCount();
```

[groupCount()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29) will return the number of capturing groups (which at least can be thought of as an upper limit of what the user may refer to).

Comment: Thanks, can I then verify that against the replace pattern to ensure $2 isn't present if there's only one group?

Comment: Note that there still may be groups that evaluate to null based on the actual text being matched. For example, the pattern `(a)|(b)` has 2 groups, but only one of them will match the text.

Comment: @Avi, that's fine in my case as I'm just wanting to validate that there are no $ back references that point to a non-existent group.